# Bootstrap collapsible navbar with search bar: form-inline does not scale well with resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

(fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/xdo6u5p6/1/)

I'm having difficulty placing a search bar into my navbar-default without having the formatting completely messed up when resizing. In desktop view, my header looks like so:

[image]

Now, if I were to resize the window width small enough (or go to mobile). The header looks like:

[image]

The search bar has kicked the list items onto the next line and looks pretty ugly. Even worse is if I resize it to the point where the menu collapses:

[image]

The root cause of the issue is my `form-inline`, because without that search bar the header works perfectly. How can I allow the header to fit everything on one line up until it collapses, then correctly align the search bar somewhere in the collapsed window? My initial guess is that setting the `margin-left` of the form inline to `70` is a big part of the problem, but I don't want the form sitting right beside the banner. Here's the html :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="../index.html" class="navbar-brand">Highli.ne</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header">
      <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search area or name" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
/* header -- begin */
.navbar-default {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #2457af;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-brand,
.navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.navbar-default .form-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.navbar-default .form-control {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
}

.navbar-default .btn-default {
    border-radius: 0;
    display: inline;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
    color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/* header -- end */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw on the Bootstrap website has the same example. Please try to modify your code to the following, the change is only removed class .form-inline from form element and add another 2 class .navbar-form and .navbar-left

```html
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search area or name" />
  </div>
</form>
```